# how to prove that $f(p(x))=p'(x)$ is a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $f: \mathbb{R}_{n}[x] \mapsto \mathbb{R}_{n}[x]$ be an application define by $f(p(x))=p'(x)$. How to prove that is a linear transformation?

I did this way:

In order to $f \space$ be a linear transformation, $2$ conditions have to be verified.

$f(p(x)+q(x))=f(p(x))+f(q(x)) \space $ **and** $\space \lambda \space f(p(x))=f(\lambda(p(x))) \space \forall \lambda \in \mathbb{R}$

For the first:

$f(p(x)+q(x))=f((p+q)(x))=(p+q)'(x)=p'(x)+q'(x)=f(p)+f(q)$

For the second:

$ \lambda \space f(p(x))=\lambda p'(x) =f(\lambda p(x))$

I'm no sure if the second is rigth.Can you help me?Thanks

---

EDIT:

I found this explanation for the first condition:

Let $p_{n}$ a polynomial whose degree do not exceed $n$. In its canonic form $p_{n}(x)=a_{0}x^n+a_{1}x^{n-1}+...+a_{n-2}x^2+a_{n-1}x+a_{n}$.

Then $ \space p_{n}'(x)=a_{0}nx^{n-1}+a_{1}(n-1)x^{n-2}+...+a_{n-2}2x+a_{n-1}$. In other words, $p'_{n}(x)$ is a polynomial whose degree do not exceed $n-1$.

$$f:\mathbb{R}_{n}[x] \mapsto \mathbb{R}_{n-1}[x]$$

Now let $q_{n}(x)$ and $p_{n}(x)$ be $2$ vectors in the same space. If the degree of $q(x)$ is not equal to the degree of $p(x)$ is because the coefficients of the inexistent degrees are zero. So,

$f(p(x))+f(q(x))=a_{0}nx^{n-1}+a_{1}(n-1)x^{n-2}+...+a_{n-2}2x+a_{n-1}+b_{0}nx^{n-1}+b_{1}(n-1)x^{n-2}+...+b_{n-2}2x+b_{n-1}$

By adding like terms,

$=(a_{0}+b_{0})nx^{n-1}+(a_{1}+b_{1})(n-1)x^{n-2}+...+(a_{n-2}+b_{n-2})2x+a_{n-1}+b_{n-1}$

That's equal to $f(p(x)+q(x))$

My doubt in the second condition is:

If ones multiplied each term of $p(x)$ by a real number $\lambda$, ones get a new coefficient for each term that is equal to $\lambda a_{k}$. Where $k=0,1,2,...,n$. These new coefficients will have the same behaviour of the previous. So,

$\lambda f(p(x))=\lambda p_{n}'(x)=\lambda a_{0}nx^{n-1}+\lambda a_{1}(n-1)x^{n-2}+...+\lambda a_{n-2}2x+\lambda a_{n-1}$

How can I integrate the $\lambda$ inside $f$?

Comment: What's $\mathbb{R}_n[x]$? Set of $n$ times differentiable functions, maybe?

Comment: @KarolisJuodelė Most likely the polynomials of degree not exceeding $n$.

Comment: Yes, the second is right: $\lambda p'=(\lambda p)'$. This is true for every differentiable function $p$. So in particular for your polynomials.

Comment: @Karolis Juodelė, as julien said its the vectorial space of real polynomials that not execeed degree $n$.Thanks julien

Comment: So your argument is that a transformation defined to be differentiation is linear because differentiation is linear? It's certainly true, but I'm not sure if that counts as a proof. Do you have any idea about what kind of assumptions you're supposed to use? I'm guessing that you should only assume $(cx^n)' = cnx^{n-1}$ and $(ax^i + bx^j)' = (ax^i)' + (bx^j)'$, but you should look at your notes/book to see what was and what wasn't proven in class...

Comment: I don't get it: why wouldn't "that" count as a proof? It certainly is once one knows the formal derivative of a polynomial renders the same result as the "usual", from-analysis, one...

Comment: This is a kind of strange question. How to prove it depends very much on what you are allowed to assume. In analysis you prove that $(\lambda f)'=\lambda f'$ and $(f+g)'=f'+g'$ for *all* differentiable functions. This is a theorem of analysis, though, not of linear algebra. So are you allowed to assume its truth? If so, there's nothing left to prove, really. If you're not allowed to assume it, then you have to prove it (Pedro's answer uses the fact implicitly, for instance), but then this is really an analysis exercise. Can you find out what assumptions you're allowed to make?

Answer (score 1):

The application in question is the usual differentiation (in this case, it seems, polynomials). What you want to prove is that

$$D(f+g)=D(f)+D(g)$$

and that

$$D(\lambda f)=\lambda D(f)$$

Note that for any polynomials $p(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n a_k x^k$ and $q(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n b_k x^k$ we have that

$$D(p(x)+q(x))=\sum (a_k+b_k) kx^{k-1}=\sum a_k kx^{k-1}+\sum b_k kx^{k-1}=D(p(x))+D(q(x))$$

For the other

$$D(\lambda p(x))=\sum \lambda a_k  kx^{k-1}=\lambda \sum a_k  kx^{k-1}=\lambda D(p(x))$$

Interpret both sum, multiplication by scalars and differentiation as an operation on the coefficients, and you'll get this much easier. We can encode a polynomial by its coefficients, say $p=(a_1,\dots,a_n),q=(b_1,\dots,b_n)$. Then we have the sum

$$p+q:=(a_0+b_0,\dots,a_n+b_n)$$

the multiplication by scalars

$$\lambda\cdot  p:=(\lambda a_0 ,\dots, \lambda a_n )$$

and differentiation

$$p':=(a_1 ,2a_2,\dots,(n-1)a_{n-1}, 0 )$$

You can try and see that with this idea (which is basically an isomorphism using coordintes over $\Bbb R^n$) we can prove all what you want, namely that

$$(p+q)'=p'+q'$$ and that $$(\lambda\cdot  p)'=\lambda\cdot  p'$$

Comment: Aren't you assuming what you're trying to prove right at the beginning, when you calculate $D(\lambda p)$ and $D(p+q)$?